# Does local variable in this case consume memory?

Tags: c

I'm writing an app on a very limited memory device, so I have to take care of every bit of memory.

I have some code like this

```
int some_func(struct some *buf) {
    func2(buf->will.be_used->very.long.pointer1);
    func3(buf->will.be_used->very.long.pointer2, buf->will.be_used->very.long.var);
}
```

The variable will be very long

So I always write this way

```
int some_func(struct some *buf) {
    char *p1 = buf->will.be_used->very.long.pointer1;
    char *p2 = buf->will.be_used->very.long.pointer2;

    int var = buf->will.be_used->very.long.var;

    func2(p1);
    func3(p2, var);
}
```

This is no big deal. I just wonder does `p1` `p2` `var` will add extra memory consumption?

Comment: You can use `sizeof` to see exactly how many bytes your local variables use.  But `p1` and `p2` are both pointers, and `var` is an int, so they shouldn't take much space (probably 4 or 8 bytes each for `p1` and `p2`, and probably 4 bytes for `var`, but again, use `sizeof` to get a definitive answer).  The memory will be freed when `some_func` returns.

Comment: The function differ. If `func3` modifier any memory pointed to by `buf`, the calls differ. The compiler will not optimize the second call, as they are different. In the first call, the `pointer2` and `var` variables need to be read after `func2` call. In the second the variables are read before `func2`. The compiler should anyway optimize them. Also, you can check generated assembly output, ex. see [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/V3gj15).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does `p1` `p2` `var` will add extra memory consumption?

It is possible that those variables will be optimized out by your compiler, especially since they are set only once each and read only once each, but the C language in no way promises that.

Moreover, as @TomKarzes observes in comments, this also requires that the compiler be able to prove that the two forms are in fact equivalent.  This would not be an issue for just `func2()`, but with the actual sequence of computations and function calls presented in the question, it is possible that computing and storing values for `p2` and `var` before calling `func2()` can yield different results than would performing the same computations afterward and passing the results directly to `func3()`.

Thus, the variables very well might consume stack space until the function returns.  If you are confident that the two forms are equivalent for your purposes, then you can make sure that the variables don't occupy space by using the first form of your function instead of leaving the decision to your compiler.

Comment: The two forms are not equivalent.  Consider the case where `func2` changes memory in a way that would affect `p2` and `var`.  The first version would pick up those changes, while the second would not.  The compiler is not free to transform the latter into the former unless it knows for a fact that this can't happen, and vice versa.  That said, the second may actually be faster, since several of the memory references can be common-subbed.  This can only partially be done in the first version.